# Yii dependent Dropdown

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I am trying to implement a dependent dropdown in which it will not retrieve its data from Database, however, i certainly would like to be save their entry in my table.
I have tried to use the tutorial of Yii i.e. 
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/
But as you can see that it is retrieving data from table but i want that an array to be populated against the selected value.

```
public function actionDynamiccities()
{
    $data=Location::model()->findAll('parent_id=:parent_id', 
                  array(':parent_id'=>(int) $_POST['country_id']));

    $data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','name');
    foreach($data as $value=>$name)
    {
        echo CHtml::tag('option',
                   array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
    }
```

Please assist
Javascript could be an option but then how would i implement it in Yii form.

Comment: please post HTML as well.

Comment: +1 for this, maybe the clientChage parametrers are not set in the view

Comment: Also, why not use `CHtml::dropDownList()`?

Comment: http://codingbin.com/dependent-drop-down-lists-in-yii/ check if it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is my example program from the given link (http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/)

```
        <!-- ===================== My First Dropdown =========== -->
        <?php
        echo CHtml::dropDownList('country_id', '', array(1 => 'USA', 2 => 'France', 3 => 'Japan'), array(
            'ajax' => array(
                'type' => 'POST', //My method type
                'url' => CController::createUrl('site/CallCities'), //This is my request/ajax URL
                array('coountry_id'=>'js:this.value'), //I'm passing the selected dropdonw value.
                'dataType' => 'JSON', 
                'success'=>'js:function(data)' //The functionaliy after success
                . '{'
                . '    var html="";'
                . '    $.each(data,function(i,obj)'
                . '    {'
                . '         html+="<option value=obj.id>"+obj.name+"</option>"'
                . '    });'
                . '    $("#city_id").html(html);'
                . '}' 

        )));
        ?>

        <!-- ===================== My Second Dropdown =========== -->
        <?php
        echo CHtml::dropDownList('city_id', '', array());
        ?>
```

And, my controller method is

```
        public function actionCallCities()
        {
            $cityId=$_POST['coountry_id'];
            $criteria=new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria->select=array('id,name');
            $criteria->condition='city_id='.$cityId;
            $criteria->order='name';
            $cityAry= MyCity::model()->findAll($criteria);
            $ary=array();
            foreach($cityAry as $i=>$obj)
            {
                $ary[$i]['id']=$obj->id;
                $ary[$i]['name']=$obj->name;            
            }
            echo json_encode($ary);
        }
```

I hope, this example program will work for you

Comment: As i already mentioned that i am looking to add cities from an array or something else, i am not interested in calling a query in a controller as you have done.